Chrome (forced to use Intel GPU) slows down when I focus on a game that uses 100% of the NVIDIA GPU
I have 2 GPUs in my Windows 10 PC:

Intel HD Graphics 4600 (On Board)
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6 GB

To allow for a better distribution of graphics performance, I changed the Windows graphics setting to force the Intel GPU to always be used when using Chrome, to relieve NVIDIA when using games.

The problem is this:

I'm running a game (which is using 100% of the NVIDIA GPU) and, at the same time, I'm playing a YouTube video, in Chrome (forced to use Intel GPU, as shown above);
When the FOCUS is on ANYTHING OTHER THAN THE GAME, the YouTube video runs with good FPS;
But when the FOCUS GOES TO THE GAME, the YouTube video IMMEDIATELY LOSES FPS.

See this video
This does NOT occur if the game is using LESS than 60 FPS.
It's as if YouTube (Chrome) used some of the NVIDIA GPU, unduly (because as shown above, Chrome is configured to use the Intel GPU forcibly).
What can be done to resolve this?

What graphics device is your display physically connected to?

NVIDIA.
However, as you can see in the image and video, Chrome IS IN FACT USING the Intel GPU. But for some reason it slows down when the NVIDIA GPU is at 100%

Chrome may be using your Intel GPU, but the Intel GPU cannot display the image on its own. It must be copied over to the NVIDIA GPU first. Which appears to be busy.

And is this due to the fact that the monitor is connected to an NVIDIA output?
